# Wife is cosigned on a credit card with her parents — real assets are also shared. How to protect my credit?

Tags: credit-score, debt, inheritance, co-sign

A few years ago I got a credit monitoring app and started watching my credit score (high 700s). It's been climbing slowly and  sends me an alert when I apply for new credit — like when I bought a car or applied for a Lowe's card.

Today I set my wife up with the same app.  Her credit score is moderately lower than mine (low 700s). We discussed the details to try and find out  why and I found out that  she had cosigned with her parents on credit cards that have been maxed out, totaling  low five figures. I didn't pitch a fit at the time.  The total debt is a major  inconvenience but it's not "We can't pay that off in our lifetime" money.

As I drove to work,  I realized that like roaches,  there may be  more issues at hand. I knew that my in-laws are not financially sound but didn't realize the magnitude. I'm not trying to be judgmental - the recession hit them hard  - but it is what it is.

Unfortunately, in addition to those cards, my wife's car is also titled to both her and her parents and more importantly, our bank account also has her mom's name on it*. Can those assets be seized in whole or in part in any unfortunate events?

Finally — my credit score seems healthy with no mention of those cards but my wife and I are married.  Are there any active steps I need to take to prevent my credit from sinking?

TL;DR — My wife is on the hook for credit card debt and the car and bank account are shared with holders of bad credit.  Can those real assets be seized? Since we are married, what do I need to do to wall off my credit score from that issue?

<sub>*I lost the fight on whose bank to go with when we got married and we just left the MIL on the account.  My wife was a preteen when they opened  the account so  they put both her and her mom on it. My MIL doesn't have a debit card or checks  so she'd have to go to the bank personally to make a withdrawal.</sub>

Comment: So your MIL can spend your money at will? That's wild. Are you in the US or another country?

Comment: I would not worry about your credit score currently. You have assets that are exposed. Most important things first. i.e. Fix the bank issue. Actually, thinking about it, time for some conflict resolution as a talk with your wife about family, finances are in order. Best of luck.

Comment: Opening bank accounts is super easy. You can have a bunch of them. You can have your own account. Your wife can have her own account. You can have a joint account between you and your wife. And you can have a three-way joint account between you, your wife, and your MIL. All at the same time! You can transfer money between them within seconds, with your phone. You can even schedule transfers so you don't even have to do anything. You can set all of this up in a day! If you think the fight for whose bank account to use was bad, think about the fight when money goes missing from the big pile.

Comment: A state tag would help. Stuff like whether it's a community property state would likely be relevant.

Comment: The MIL's name *should* have come off the daughter's account shortly after the daughter turned 18.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question, new user.  BTW "our bank account also has her mom's name on it"  As everyone has mentioned, that is really, really strange (no matter what country) and needs to be fixed.  You can open a new bank act in 2 minutes.

Comment: Question: does the mother-daughter bank account allow survivorship rights? If one holder dies, does the other own the bank account?

Comment: `real assets are also shared` - A credit card is not an asset, it is a liability. Usually with a sizeable interest rate attached somewhere :-)

Comment: `My wife was a preteen when they opened the account` that's an almost-certain indication that there are way better bank accounts available for your benefit. Worth investigating.

Comment: If you lost a fight over what back account to use, I can only imagine you didn't sign a pre-nup either. OP, if you don't fix these things quickly, you could be in some deep shit.

Comment: @Fattie Co-ownership of an account within family is not strange at all. The benefit is that it simplifies lots of cases of emergency or death (shared account is excluded from estate). Eg, I'm equal rights co-owner of my dad's account, and so was he with his dad before. The problem here is the **reason** to having it that way. The reason "because it was so before" sounds like they're either too financially illiterate to understand the implications, too lazy to do something about it, or outright plan to con OP in case his relationship goes sour. Either way, it has to be changed.

Answer (score 84):

Is your name on your account at all? If yes, you go to the bank tomorrow morning, open an account in your name, and move all the money over. Then tell your company to change their payments to the new account. After that, you explain to your wife. This is madness. (I’d recommend the same to your wife if a member of your family was on that account).

If your mother in law gets into trouble and bailiffs want money, they will go straight to the bank account with your money. If she dies and leaves everything to charity, they will go straight to your account.

If your name isn’t on it, talk to your wife because then she needs to take action.

Comment: A thousand yesses - my bank transferred out 5k from my savings account for a debt my father owed them.  I hadn't realized he was still on the account from when he opened it for me when I was born.

Comment: And yet (if he's in one of many states in the US), he can still be responsible for any debts his wife incurs and is unable to pay.  The good news in this scenario is that once he cuts his wife and her family off, she'll hate him, and divorce (with a good lawyer) will come to the rescue.

Comment: "If she dies and leaves everything to charity, they will go straight to your account." No, if she dies, the bank account will not become part of the estate.

Comment: "if she dies and leaves everything to charity", IANAL, but I'm pretty sure creditors get paid off before assets are distributed. If that wasn't so, then any will that said "I leave everything to my son" would leave all the creditors high and dry.

Comment: @dsolimano: Please tell me you fought that one with the bank. The money obviously wasn't his.

Comment: @Joshua fought for a while but they were quite clear they considered joint accounts to be joint property.

Comment: Making such a move without telling the wife first is  a recipe for divorce.  Then again, if you have to do it without telling the wife first, divorce may be inevitable.

Comment: @Joshua The very point of a co-owned account is that everything on it is co-owned. The money **was** father's, as much as they were dsolimano's. There was nothing dsolimano could fight, he **gave** the money to his father the second he transferred them to their account (and he took it from him with every withdrawal). For this very reason I am co-owner of my dad's account, even though I never even look at it. But "his" money are as much mine as his, when he dies or goes sick, neither my sister nor anyone in the world could do anything about it.

Comment: @Agent_L: The father's name on a minor's account is a well-known legal fiction. Money he put in later does not become the father's money.

Comment: @Joshua No. Thinking that this money is yours because you put them there is what's legal fiction. Co-owned means co-owned, law is very precise about that.

Answer (score 29):

> Can those assets in whole or in part be seized in any unfortunate
>   events?

If the vehicle is used by your wife primarily, then it is likely not at risk. The bank account is, the extent to which you are exposed depends on the state. In some states joint assets are considered equally owned while in others the ownership would be assessed based on contribution (in the context of bankruptcy). The greater risk is that they have access to your account, maybe they'd never use your funds, but who wants to find out?

> Finally -- my credit score seems healthy with no mention of those
>   cards, but my wife and I are married -- are there any active steps I
>   need to take to prevent my credit from sinking?

Your wife's credit score will not affect yours, but if you ever apply for a loan together her score can hurt you. As a co-signer, she is on the hook for any unpaid bills, that is much more likely to hurt you than her credit score.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have to trust my in-laws wouldn't use our funds (and implying otherwise to my wife would be for more damaging to my relationship if they actually did, risk management and all that), but I'm kind of concerned about credit agencies attempting to collect on the bank account (and not being able to stop them) should the worst happen. Do you know what relevant search terms I'd use to determine the laws in my state?

Comment: @anonibon I'd be more worried about you MIL collecting on the bank account. Technology has made it possible to easily transfer money between accounts at any time within seconds. There's literally no reason to share a primary account with another human anymore. If you absolutely need a three-way joint account, make one and transfer money to it regularly from your primary account. You can even set up automatic scheduling!

Comment: "There's literally no reason to share a primary account with another human anymore." I suspect you meant to except couples and minors.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus No, I didn't. Seriously, there is absolutely no reason to share a primary account. It's great to have joint accounts with your spouse, children, even your adult children if the situation warrants. They just really shouldn't be anyone's primary account (except the child's, if they couldn't get an account otherwise). Sharing a primary account is like giving someone a stack of 100 separate $1 bills and instructing them to only spend $1. Why not just give them $1 and keep the rest in your pocket??

Comment: @AndrewLazarus it also shows the account users do not actually track their money if they pile multiple people's expenses and income into a giant account.  How do you even figure out who's money is who's?  How do you even distinguish who made what cash withdrawal?  Absolute accounting nightmare.

Comment: Given that I live in a community property state, there is no point to separating out mine and my wife's wages, and we don't have to argue whose turn it is to pay the electric bill. For our cash management accounts (stocks plus checkwriting and debit card) it would be a nightmare. Buy 50 shares of XYZ each? We also have separate accounts, consisting of inherited money, which is not community property.

Comment: @Clay07g, nelson I have to disagree with you. I see absolutely no reason for my wife and I to have separate accounts no matter how easy it is to transfer money between them. Separate accounts indicates my money and her money which is something I simply don't believe in. It's all our money. We pay our bills with our money. We make decisions on what to spend it on together. There is no my money and her money anymore. This was true when got married and were both working. It is still true now that she's staying home with our son and I'm the only one working.

Comment: @Nelson "How do you even figure out who's money is who's?" For spouses, you don't. In many states there's no such thing as the money belonging to one of you or the other. If either of your names is on the account, the money legally belongs to both of you. And many couples who don't live in such states choose to operate their finances that way because it leads to a happier marriage when you treat property as "ours" rather than "mine or theirs."

Comment: @Nelson The MIL is simply a name on the account. She doesn't actually make deposits or own that money.

Comment: Name on the account means the MIL can remove money.

Comment: @anonibon are you really sure that you wife would react so badly if you said that you were uncomfortable about having a shared bank account with your in-laws? I ask because it seems a very unusual setup to me, so unless there are cultural sensitivities in play it is a totally reasonable thing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 20):

You ask a good question, but I think you are sadly mistaken in some of your views on personal finance.  The first is a that a good credit score for you has much value.  It has some, but credit score does not indicate wealth.  The second misconception is that you are somewhat insulated from your wife's financial condition.  You aren't and the bad things that are looming will happen to you as well.

The first thing, obviously, would be to have your MIL removed from your wife's bank account.  The bank account should be for you and her both, and no one else.  My wife and I have different bank accounts, however, we are both signers on each others.  It is, really preferable that you two have one account so you can learn to work together on personal finance.

Secondly the credit cards in question need to be closed.  MIL and FIL will have to fend for themselves with the revolving credit.  However you two will have to pay these bills off yourselves.  They don't have any money, and if they did they would manage it poorly anyway.  It sucks but better to deal with it now then when the balances grow even larger.

Sure you can probably maintain your credit, and that bank account will not likely be seized, but that is not really the point.  This mess needs to be cleaned up and you really do not want your financial future tied to these people.

Comment: I have to disagree with your first point.  A good credit score is important and can really affect the amount you pay on your major purchases.  Do you need to worry about every last point once you get into the high 700s?  Maybe not, but it is something you need to be mindful of.

Comment: Before taking the MIL/FIL off the credit card, see if the OP can take the wife's name off the card.  That fixes things much faster, without literally taking on her parents debt.  If the CC won't take off the wife's name, they probably won't take off the parent(s) either, so that's a no-win there.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Pete B says your credit score does not matter because he is a strong believer in paying cash for everything.

Comment: If the parents are maxed-out but not actually delinquent is there actually anything the co-signer can do to end the arrangement?

Comment: I tend to agree with Pete B. I have been without debt long enough that I have no credit score, and it has never stopped me from buying anything I needed. A bonus is that timeshare salesmen don't bother me any more.

Comment: @PeterGreen The whole point of being a co-signer is that you can't get out of it.

Comment: The whole point of co-signing is that you can't get out of paying the debt if the co-signee fails to pay for it. My question was if you co-sign for a credit card (which unlike a loan has no fixed end date) are you stuck as a cosigner forever? or is there some way to end the arrangement (potentially paying outstanding debt but not future debt)?

Answer (score 15):

You have a mix of family and financial problems here. What's smart to do financially may cause conflict in the family, and you have to consider that.

First question to me is why you set up these accounts like this. If your in-laws have bad credit and can't get a credit card without your wife cosigning it or some such, then getting out of this situation will put your in-laws in trouble, and thus presumably cause family problems. If it was just a matter of "oh, seemed like a good idea at the time", then much easier.

As others have said, this is a very dangerous situation. You're essentially giving your in-laws the legal right to spend unlimited amounts of your money and to run up debts for which you are liable. Even assuming that they do not deliberately take advantage of you, if they are irresponsible or careless they could cause you major problems.

Easy step 1: Stop using the bank account that your wife shares with your in-laws. Open a new account and put your money there -- that is, the money that belong to you and your wife as opposed to money that belongs to your in-laws -- not in the joint account. Withdraw your share of the money from the joint account and put it in the new account.

Step 2: As long as you don't deposit to the joint account, you reduce your risk, but you don't eliminate it. If your in-laws overdraw the account, as long as your wife's name is on it, you're still liable. So get your wife's name off the account, or close it. I've never tried to take one name off an account, frankly I'm not sure how that works with the bank. I don't see why they wouldn't agree to remove your name from an account that has money in it -- you're giving up an asset. That's not at all the same as saying "take this other person's name off this account". That would have the obvious potential to be trying to steal someone else's share of the money.

Step 3: You need to close the credit card account. I'd tell the in-laws that this account is hurting your credit rating and you need to close it. They are certainly free to open up a new account on their own, you couldn't stop them from doing that if you wanted to. If they don't accept that, there could be a family fight, but I think you have to bite the bullet and do it. When you close a credit card where you still owe money, of course you still have to pay off the existing balance, but the bank will de-activate the card so no new purchases can be put on it. Once you pay it off, the account will completely close.

Of course all this depends on your wife agreeing to go along with these steps. If she says "no, I want to keep these accounts" for some reason, you have a family problem. How you deal with that is an entirely different kind of question. Whether by threatening to break china as gnasher729 suggests, going to a marriage counselor, murdering her and disposing of the body, or what. It may not be possible to separate your finances from your wife's. In community property states, the law explicitly says that all property is owned jointly. I'm not sure how it would work in other US states and other countries.

Comment: "Withdraw your share of the money from the joint account and put it in the new account." Suggest rephrasing this. As noted in comments on some other answers, viewing money as belonging to one or the other can cause conflict in marriage (and similarly, viewing everything as belonging to both reduces it). In 3, I'd also emphasize that it's hurting *their daughter*, rather than the OP. ...And the murder bit is not really funny. =/ Otherwise +1.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get someone's name off an account, I had cause to try with a co-signed bank account but was told the bank's official method was to open a new account and close the old, instead of modifying the account holders.  Might be different in different banks, different areas but might not be.

Comment: @jpmc26 The answer is referring the couple's share versus the parent's share.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, as TheGreatDuck says, by "your" in my answer I meant "you and your wife" as distinct from "her parents", not "you" as distinct from "your wife".

Comment: @Megha Possibly so, I've never tried to take a name off an account. When my wife left me, we divided what was in the joint account and closed it. I opened a new account in my name only. (She already had accounts in her name only that she'd never told me about and where she was hiding money from me and the divorce court, but that's another story).

Comment: @jpmc26 "viewing money as belonging to one or the other can cause conflict in marriage" Maybe so and I don't suggest doing that. But for those posters who do make such a suggestion, I don't think you can just make a blanket statement "don't do it, it causes conflict". You'd have to discuss pros and cons.

Answer (score 9):

From my experience, this is an **emergency**. Sorry to say. I think you know the first problem you must work on is **interpersonal, not financial**.

Why is it an emergency?

- your wife didn't tell you about this situation before your wedding.
- her bank account belongs to her mother.
- the credit cards with high balances on them are a bright red flag.
- you've said confronting your wife with this situation will damage your relationship. Ask yourself whether she has, by keeping secrets, damaged your relationship.

If I were you (I've been you, when my spouse and our adult child had shared credit cards) I'd deal with this right away.

What if somebody in your wife's parents' household has, or gets, gambling or drug problems? Rationality and fairness will not be factors in that case.

**First**, I'd find a **competent marriage counselor** to help you strategize this, and to be on-call if it causes a huge blowup in your marriage.

**Second**, I would ask my wife to **kill the credit cards** to which her parents are making charges. By "kill" I mean tell the card companies to disallow future charges. Your wife can get a new credit card in her sole name. She should do it immediately, without giving you excuses, because of the accrued debt. If she doesn't, that's why you have the marriage counselor. You need to be **polite but unbending** about this.

You can start the conversation by saying, "when I found out your parents ran up a lot of debt on your credit cards, I honestly felt betrayed and frightened. We need to be in this together. Please, let's work together to sort this out. I think the first step is ...  What do you think?"

The formula:

- describe the bad behavior
- explain its emotional effect on you
- ask for a realistic change
- offer to help.

**Third**, once the second step is done, I'd ask her to open a **bank account in her own name** and move the balance of the joint account to the new account. And, if your wife's employer direct-deposits her pay, move that to the new account.

**Fourth**, I would ask your wife "**is there anything else**?"

**Fifth**, I would have a conversation with her about how your household can **support her parents' household**. Do they need money? If so you can figure out how to give them some, perhaps by making a regular deposit to the joint account.

**Sixth**, you and your wife should be on the same page, or close to it by now. Have a conversation with her parents about money and so forth. Keep in mind that the conversation will really be about your mother-in-law losing her baby girl.

Good luck and courage  to you.

Answer (score 3):

A few things I would add that have not been mentioned in other answers:

1) You should determine whether you live in a [common law property](https://family.findlaw.com/marriage/what-s-mine-is-mine-what-s-yours-is-mine-who-owns-what-in.html) state or not as this can significantly change how much liability you are incurring from her financial entanglements.

2) Regardless of if you live in a common law property state or not, her credit score is not a huge issue in most cases if you are okay not including her on titles.  For instance, when I bought my house, my wife did not have much credit.  We actually had to take her off the mortgage paperwork to get the loan approved, even though I live in a community law property state (see previous link) so she was just as much an owner as I was, regardless of what the mortgage or title says.

3) Especially if you live in a community law property state, and you are worried, you may want to approach your wife about drafting paperwork where she willingly signs over big ticket items to you, or to a trust you setup that she is not part of (except in the event of your death).  This will give you a fighting chance if it ever becomes an issue, and will certainly complicate the process of a third-party taking your property.  Of course, this requires significant, mutual trust.

4) Repeating a bit of what others have said, you should create your own bank account, and your wife should create her own bank account without her parents on it.  This at least will require much more court involvement for a third-party to access the money.  If the parents' names are on the account or on the car, they are fair game for reprisal on loan default. Get the car transferred to your wife or even better, to you, as soon as possible.

Comment: I think you mean a "community property state", not "common law property state". (Unless there's another type of law that I'm not familiar with.)

Comment: @Jay Click the link, there are explanations of both

Comment: You should write a stand-alone answer. As a reader I have no idea what you mean by "the previous comments" because answers are not sorted chronologically, and can be edited at any time.

Comment: @JollyJoker I stand corrected. I'd never heard the term "common law property state" before.

Comment: I think this answer has common law property vs. community property laws reversed. It's community property states where both of you own it if one your names is on the title. According to the provided link, common law property laws say the opposite: "The common law system provides that property acquired by one member of a married couple is owned completely and solely by that person."

Comment: An excellent answer from a new user.

Comment: @reirab You were correct, I've updated the answer.